# How to extend initComplete Datatables ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
  }
} );
```

How to extends initComplete like oLanguange ?

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults.oLanguage, {
 "sSearch": "<label>Record per page</label> _INPUT_ "
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on( 'init.dt', function ( e, settings ) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

    if ( api.init().pageResize ||
         $.fn.dataTable.defaults.pageResize )
    {
        new PageResize( api );
   }
} );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/init()